# Simple programs for recording chess games -- Like ECTool -- for Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: software

I should be able to google this, but I don't know what the name for this item is:

I'm looking for a simple program that can be used to record and play back a chess game. I'm *not* looking for a computer program to play against, and I'm *not* looking for a client to connect to an ICS.

I just want to record the moves of an old-fashioned postal game.

Any suggestions for free programs that do this? I'd like suggestions for both Ubuntu and Windows.

**Update:**
I recall using [ECTool](http://webs.ono.com/a.valverde/ectool.htm) for this purpose in a previous century, but it seems to be not maintained beyond Windows XP.

Comment: I would tag this question 'mail chess' or 'postal chess', and 'windows', and 'ubuntu' if I could create tags.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me like what you want is a chess database program. If so, the one I would recommend is [Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/), which is totally free, and comes in Windows, Linux and Mac flavors.

Answer (score 3):

I use Zillions of games to record moves for my correspondence games. Over a few years of playing, I have created more than 2,000 files. You can get it for free: http://www.zillions-of-games.com and it knows other games than chess - and it also plays games.