# Easy to use, MS Word-like tool to record chess games

Tags: software, scid

Apologies for being a noob in this matter - a senior citizen friend of mine is looking for desktop publishing-like software to record chess games (diagrams along with personal reflection). The goal is personal publishing of chess games from their history. He is familiar with MS Word, but not much with other software.

From what I can see, existing software is aimed at [creating Portable Game Notation files](http://www.chess.com/analysis-board-editor), which can be [played back online](http://kvchess.com/publish.html), or is a powerful chess game database like [Scid](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1708/simple-programs-for-recording-chess-games-like-ectool-for-ubuntu-and-windo).

Is there some software for recording chess games that's closer to MS Word? I'd imagine it basically like a text editor, with a chess board on the side that can be configured with a certain position, then an image of it would be inserted in the text editor. No playback capabilities are required.

Comment: Nicest text-based way of working chess documentation is LaTeX. Though that comes with a learning curve and probably not meant for WYSIWYG users such as the person you've described. Have you simply asked him to use a wordpress type blog (where the editor/plugins allows you to easily embed boards of positions or full games with variations?)
I think you can find a way to post-process the blog into a PDF, ePub or other document format once you've got the content all squared away.

Answer (score 5):

The closest thing I can think of to what you want, though it is still PGN file based, is ChessPad.  http://www.wmlsoftware.com/chesspad.html.  It's a very basic pgn file editor/viewer which maybe your friend could use standalone, or he could use it to create diagrams which he then pastes into MS Word.

Comment: ChessPad can print the game, with an elegant format and if you have installed a chessfont, can use figurines. You can print one or two column per page.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste into PGN.(nearly every site will let you do this)

You can then save PGN into a Word document.

You can then copy and paste back into whatever you want. Lichess offers a database and very strong engine but you can pick whatever software you want.